# Using MVC to talk directly to Amazon S3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3

I am writing an MVC 3 application that needs to allow the user to directly upload a file to S3.  I also need to show a progress bar.  All of the examples I have seen are PHP or Ruby-on-Rails related.  Has anyone managed to upload a file to S3 directly (from client browser) using MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after a morning of smashing my head into my keyboard, the following snippet of code works (with the obvious credentials removed):

```
using (AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client("Access_Key", 
                                                                      "Secret_Key"))
{
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
    request.WithBucketName("BUCKET-NAME")
           .WithCannedACL(S3CannedACL.PublicRead)
           .WithKey("myDirectory/" + 
                    HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(fileBase.FileName))
           .InputStream = fileBase.InputStream;
    S3Response response = client.PutObject(request);
}
```

Comment: Where does the fileBase come from?